# Prove a relation

Tags: polynomials

Prove that $$ a = b = c \quad or \quad  ab + bc + ca = 0 $$ holds if $ R = 0$. Given that,

$$ R = \frac{1}{a^3} + \frac{1}{b^3} + \frac{1}{c^3} - \frac{3}{abc} $$

I've gotten this far,

$$ a^3b^3 + b^3c^3 + c^3a^3 = 3a^2b^2c^2 $$

But I can't seem to factorise this.

Comment: What have you tried? Mention what you have done so far by editing the post.

Comment: I have edited my post. @ShubhamJohri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Take $A=1/a,B=1/b,C=1/c$ and use this standard identity:$$A^3+B^3+C^3-3ABC=(A+B+C)(A^2+B^2+C^2-AB-AC-BC)$$You may need to use the fact$$A^2+B^2+C^2-AB-AC-BC=\frac12\left[\right(A-B)^2+(B-C)^2+(A-C)^2]$$

Comment: Thank you. This is crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
&b^3c^3+c^3a^3+a^3b^3-3a^2b^2c^2 = \\ &(ab+bc+ca)( b^2c^2+c^2a^2+a^2b^2 -abc(a+b+c)).
\end{eqnarray*}
How could we rewrite the second bracket ?